# T-sql How to get all rows 'between' two other rows

Tags: sql, t-sql

Suppose I have the following table:

```
Table: Score
field: ID: uniqueidentifier
field: Departmentid: int
field: Score: float
field: EnteredOn: DateTime
```

How can I devise a query which gives me all scores that are between an entry in department 115 and department 119?

To clarify: if I have the following records:

```
Id, departmentid, score
<some guid>, 115, 1
<some guid>, 100, 2
<some guid>, 119, 3
<some guid>, 115, 2
<some guid>, 102, 1
<some guid>, 119, 4
<some guid>, 115, 2
<some guid>, 100, 4
<some guid>, 120, 4
```

The query would need to retrieve the following records:

```
<some guid>, 100, 2
<some guid>, 102, 1
```

because they are between 115 and 119 records.

The records will be sorted on EntereOn by default.

Comment: If the department ids went 115, 100, 119, 102, 119...would 102 be included? Or can it be assumed that 115 and 119 always travel in pairs?

Comment: How do you determine what the latest entry for a departmentid is?

Comment: Do you have a field (or fields) which you can supply to an ORDER BY clause that will guarantee the wields will appear in the order you show them above?  Unless the order can be established with an ORDER BY, this can not be guarnateed to work.  *(SQL only ever guarantees ordering with ORDER BY, and your logic is dependant on that ordering.)*

Comment: Is guid auto_increment integer ?

Comment: @CodeByMoonlight They do not always travel in pairs.

Comment: @Dems Yes, they are chronological, so the EnteredOn should do

Comment: @jit no its just a random guid every time

Comment: @Sam: Where they do travel in pairs, will there always be one and only one row between them?

Comment: @MarkBannister Not necessarily, no

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not pretty but it works for your sample data.

```
declare @Score table
(
  ID int identity primary key,
  DepartmentID int,
  Score int,
  EnteredOn int
)

insert into @Score values
(115, 1, 1),
(100, 2, 2),
(119, 3, 3),
(115, 2, 4),
(102, 1, 5),
(119, 4, 6),
(115, 2, 7),
(100, 4, 8),
(120, 4, 9)

;with C1 as
(
  select *,
         row_number() over(order by EnteredOn) as rn
  from @Score
), C2 as
(
  select rn,
         row_number() over(order by EnteredOn) as rn2
  from C1
  where DepartmentID = 115
), C3 as
(
  select rn,
         row_number() over(order by EnteredOn) as rn2
  from C1
  where DepartmentID = 119 and rn > (select min(rn) from C2)
), C4 as
(
  select C2.rn as FromRn,
         C3.rn as ToRn
  from C2 
    inner join C3
      on C2.rn2 = C3.rn2
)
select C1.ID, C1.DepartmentID, C1.Score
from C1
  inner join C4
    on C1.rn > C4.FromRn and
       C1.rn < C4.ToRn
```

Comment: Doh, I assumed rows only returned if they were immediately preceded by 115 and immediately succeeded by 119 (so only ever one row per group).  I don't know which is right, but this works for your interpretation :)

Comment: In C3...  `AND rn > (SELECT MIN(rn) FROM C2)`?

Comment: @Dems - Yes.. that would take care of the situation when there are a 119 before the first 115. ... right? :)

Comment: @MikaelEriksson: This solution currently doesn't handle situations where there are unpaired 115s prior to a 115-119 pair.

Comment: Or `115, 119, 119, 115, 119`... And other messy situations.  Seems correlated sub-queries may be the way to go...

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to avoid correlated sub-queries, but with the need for multiple records between 115 and 119, I think it's needed.  Here is an alternative to MarkBanister's answer *(using one correlated sub-query, rather than two, but with three joins instead of two)*.

I haven't tested which performs better.

```
SELECT
  data_between.*
FROM
  Score      AS data_115
INNER JOIN
  Score      AS data_119
    ON data_119.EnteredOn = (SELECT MIN(EnteredOn) FROM Score WHERE DepartmentId IN (115, 119) AND EnteredOn > data_115.EnteredOn)
INNER JOIN
  Score      AS data_between
    ON  data_between.EnteredOn > data_115.EnteredOn
    AND data_between.EnteredOn < data_119.EnteredOn
WHERE
    data_115.DepartmentId = 115
AND data_119.DepartmentId = 119
```

Comment: @sam - I assumed you only wanted the a single row between 115 and 119, and if there were more rows, you didn't want them.  Is that correct or incorrect?

Comment: actually, I'd like ALL rows between 115 and 119, sorry for the confusion

Comment: @Sam - Then you want MikaelEriksson's answer :)  Same concept, but multiple rows, instead of just one :)

Comment: @Sam - Alternative query added to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select m.*
from MyTable m
join (select ms.EnteredOn StartDate,
             (select min(me.EnteredOn) 
              from MyTable me 
              where me.Departmentid = 119 and 
                    me.EnteredOn > ms.EnteredOn) EndDate
      from MyTable ms
      where ms.Departmentid = 115) mr
on m.EnteredOn > mr.StartDate and m.EnteredOn < mr.EndDate
where not exists
(select null
 from MyTable mn 
 where mn.Departmentid = 115 and 
       mn.EnteredOn > mr.StartDate and 
       mn.EnteredOn < mr.EndDate)
```